# Infinite loop behaviour in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 1, b = 8;
    while(a != b)
    {
        printf("asd");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, the program never stops. But why is "asd" not printed at all?

EDIT: This is the complete program. There are not any other lines. The first time I used Eclipse and MinGW and it didn't print anything. I tried then with gcc in linux and it was working as expected, even without fflush!
So probably this behaviour  might be caused by the fact that some compilers optimize the code and modify the infinite loops.

Comment: stdin is input coming to your prorgam, *stdout* is the stream you want to flush

Comment: What happened to "too localized"?

Comment: What do you mean 'modify the infinite loops'?  Can't you just look at the generated machine code?

Comment: @Sorin post generated machine code . From this it would be clear if it is cause of compiler version . cause i stated previously even without flush it shoud be printing . And check this too:if inside run command you are redirecting stdout to file

Answer (score 11):

`fflush(stdin)` is meaningless, and in fact causes undefined behaviour according to the standard - you probably meant `fflush(stdout)`.  If you make that change, you'll see output.

Comment: Stupid 60-second answer limit wouldn't let me answer first :P

Comment: Sometimes (often) the easy ones get the most votes.  If it makes you feel better, I hit the rep cap already today, so I'm not getting any internet hugs from this one.

Comment: stdout is what I meant to write. I modified the program and it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing correctly?  Your program is fine other than that problem.  Strictly speaking it needs a `#include <stdio.h>`, too.

Comment: @Sorin I'm going to guess you're doing something else with this program that you haven't mentioned

Comment: @QWR with the `stdin`, anything can happen.  If it's fixed to `stdout`, there should be output.  I'm not sure I see what you're asking?

Comment: @CarlNorum this is all my code. The library and the main function from my post.

Comment: What library?  If your program doesn't work as-is, please show us how you build & test it.  The program itself is fine, so the problem must be in one of the other steps.

Comment: @CarlNorum I was talking about stdio.h. I tried with another compiler and it works as expected, so maybe it is something special at MinGW. I modified my initial post.